# Failed to Connect to device 0! Reason: Emulator 0 terminated while waiting for it to register!

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me

While running the midlet, I am getting this error:-

**Error**:

> Failed to connect to device 0!
>   reason: Emulator 0 terminated while
>   waiting for it to register!

I am using Netbeans 6.9 with JDK 1.7
The same error comes with Netbeans 7.0 too.

I have searched a lot on the same, but I'm unable to solve this issue, as I have tried every option available.

Any help is very appreciated

Thanks,
Disha

Answer (score 0):

DEP(data execution prevention) of windows 7 preventing emulator from run.

just turn off DEP or add  
to exception list.

u can access DEP settings from 
Control Panel\System and Security\System\advanced system settings\performance\settings\data execution prevention.
Also [Check this link](http://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/first_aid_when_emulator_doesn)

Thanks

Comment: Hi sajid!! Thanks for replying....But all these option on the link..I have tried all of them already..but still its not working :( Please if u could suggest me some other way to come out of this issue?

Comment: No I have copied that Microsoft.VC80.CRT from runtimes\\cdc-hi\\bin and pasted at runtimes\\cldc-hi-javafx\\bin as mentioned...didnt work...

Comment: Also go  Tool/java platforms and refresh the Java Platform Micro Edition.

Comment: There is problem not big..... But we have to find solution. OK try other options also which you know.